# Autofac OWIN Web API current scope

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

In a OWIN Web API method you can get the current scope within a Web API method like so...

```
public IHttpActionResult GetTaxRate()
{                        
    var scope = Request.GetOwinContext().GetAutofacLifetimeScope();

    ISomething mySomething = scope.Resolve<ISomething>();
```

Is there anyway to get the current scope through a static method instead of a member on the ApiController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Nope.

Autofac puts its request scope in the OWIN context so it can be shared across middleware components, so the question of how to access the *Autofac-specific scope* from an OWIN context is more a question of "How do you get the OWIN context?" OWIN doesn't have a static mechanism like `HttpContext`, so you're stuck there. That's not an Autofac issue, that's the design of OWIN.

Web API in particular also doesn't have a static notion of something like `HttpContext`. That's a Web API restriction, not an Autofac restriction. The request scope (and other request context things) in Web API flows with the *request message*. [There's some Autofac-specific doc on this here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) but, again, this isn't an Autofac-specific issue - it's the design of Web API.